# IIS URL Rewrite - Ecluding Joomla Paths/Articles Hybrid Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, joomla2.5

I have searched for a couple of days and am struggling to achieve this, I have a partial solution that almost works.

Scenario

Web Site A - Joomla site
Web Site B - Asp.Net/MVC site

Problem

- Mobile only traffic to site A needs to be redirected to site B, however I need to allow three specific exceptions to this rule to allow mobile traffic to continue to a select few pages on Site A all other requests get redirected to B
- Desktop traffic to site A can continue to site A

I currently have the following rule:

```
<match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />

<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">


    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
</conditions>

<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.siteb.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
```

The above works but does not allow for the exceptions below, I need to allow exceptions for the following paths.

```
http://www.sitea.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56&Itemid=206
http://www.sitea.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=35&Itemid=205
http://www.sitea.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=193&Itemid=302
```

Greatly appreciate any help, getting a sore forehead.